# backbone-rails: redirection to a controller action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4, backbone-rails

I am using rails-backbone gem for the first time. I have to doubt in how to redirect in using backbone. Following the steps that i followed as provided at github's page and everything is working fine. but when i see my controller it contains the following line in **create action**

```
respond_to do |format|
      if @login.save
        format.html { redirect_to @login, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @login }
```

which works great but I can see that for **json object** it renders show action and hence not possible to reload the page as it takes **ID as attribute**, I can use a **static page** for display is one **solution** but i need it to redirect it to show action **rather than rendering** it as done when the **format is html**. how can that be done?

This is my complete controller:

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_login, only: [:show]

  def index
  end

  def new
      @login = Login.new
  end
  def show

  end
    def create
            @login = Login.new(login_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @login.save
        format.html { redirect_to @login, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @login }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @login.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def set_login
      @login = Login.find(params[:id])
    end
    def login_params
            params.require(:login).permit(:email, :password)
    end
end
```

Comment: You are not able to reload because of the way you are using the JSON and not because there is no redirect for JSON response. JSON happens in background i.e AJAX so redirect/no redirect it won't change anything in the response you get. If you want you could redirect user yourself in the Javascript using the JSON response you receive.

Comment: i guess the same. reload should happen there may be an error in the way i used my object.

Comment: anyways i have updated the question see if you find any error on my controller

Comment: Sorry, I am not backbone expert and you would need to do changes in HTML/JS to make it work. The controller looks okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.
1)In you controller instead of rendering json object, just create create.js.erb under views/logins then put js code to redirecting the page. It should be something like this,

create.js.erb:

```
window.location.href = <%= users_path(@user) %>
```

2) You can execute this window redirection js code in the backbone callback after the successfull creation of record. Please refer this backbone affcial website to know how to success callback.